# Flask: Suspend other requests while a certain one is being handled

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm running a REST server using Flask, and I have a method that updates some variables that other methods only read. I'd like to be able to safely update these variables, but I'm not sure how to approach this:

- Is there some built-in Flask feature to suspend other requests while a specific one is being handled? If that method isn't running, other methods are free to run concurrently.
- Perhaps I need to use some thread lock? I reviewed the locks Python's threading library has to offer, and couldn't find a lock that offers two kinds of locking: for writing and for reading. Do I need to implement such a thing myself?

Answer (score 1):

I think a lock probably is what you want; an example of how to use one is as follows:

```
from threading import RLock

class App(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = RLock()

        self._thing = 0

    def read_thing(self):
        with self._lock:
            print self._thing

    def write_thing(self)
        with self._lock:
            self._thing += 1
```

So, let's imagine this object of ours (App) is created and then accessed from two different threads (e.g. two different requests); the lock object is used in a context-management fashion (the "with" keyword) to ensure that all operations that could be thread-unsafe are done within the lock.

Somewhere at the low level some magic is done to ensure that for the duration that the lock is held, nothing else happens to that variable.

This means we can spam read_thing and write_thing to our hearts contents in as many threads as we like, and we shouldn't break anything.

So, for your Flask app, declare a lock and then whenever you access those variables you're worried about, do so inside the lock.

NOTE: If you're working with dictionaries, be sure to take copies of the dictionary ("copy.deepcopy" is one way), because otherwise you'll pass a reference to the actual dictionary and you'll be back to being thread-unsafe.

Comment: I feel that I'm missing something. The difference between Lock and RLock is that RLock can be acquired multiple times by the same thread (and other than that they work the same), but since every request is a thread, it means that two read requests wouldn't run together because one of them acquired the lock first, no? I want the write request to run exclusively, but the read requests shouldn't lock each other out.

Comment: Well, if you have a big method that does a bunch of stuff and then accesses the variables you're concerned about, you should only acquire the lock around the access to the variable. As with everything, give it a test- knock up a quick multi-threaded application that maybe has like 3 reader threads and 1 writer thread (all from/to the same variable) and check to see what sort of delays you have using the locks.

Comment: In fact, here's an example I knocked up- [Gist](https://gist.github.com/initialed85/821ed2109d531d897bdc56504df86075)